# Adding New Content To Drupal 7 Won't Work

Tags: drupal, content-management-system, drupal-7

For some reason Drupal 7 won't let me edit or add new content types. I have checked the permissions/cleared all the caches, and still nothing is coming up.

I don't know how else to describe the problem other than a screenshot, so here it is

[image: click here]

Has anyone ran into a similar problem and/or have a solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the screenshot right at the bottom it looks like the page has not been loaded completely. It says waiting for some ip number.

Comment: That was just in the screenshot at the time, sorry about that. It does load completely though.

Comment: Can you check the error logs and see if you see any errors. IF you have access to php config files make sure the error reporting is set to report all errors or else place this in the index.php error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE); If you find anything in the error log then you can try and compare it with one of the errors on this page http://drupal.org/node/201875